# Designing a network architecture

Tags: active-directory, exchange, network-design

I am building a network architecture from scratch for a small company (~20 users). I plan to use the "classical" model:
-A server that contains Active Directory
-A server that contains Exchange server

1 - Can we use Microsoft exchange without Microsoft active directory (ie not have a AD server at all)?
2- In order to have a fail-safe architecture, do we need 2 Domain controllers and 2 exhange servers (ie 4 in total)? or do we only need 2 domain controllers and 1 exchange server?

Thank you.

PS. Sorry guys for being lazy. I will hire a consultant certainly but at least I have an idea now about what to do. Thank you.

Comment: You're asking if you can use Exchange without having AD. You really need to hire a professional.

Comment: While you might need 4 servers for full redundancy (depending on your requirements as mentioned in the Answers), these could be run on as few as two physical servers using virtualization (ESX or Hyper-V would be recommended)

Answer (score 6):

1) no, you need AD

2) It depends how much downtime is acceptable in the event of a failure. If you don't want to restore mail databases from backup, then have two Exchange servers and use DAGs. If you're OK going to tape for a restore in the event of a failure, then do one Exchange server. Definitely two DCs though. Always at least two DCs.

Answer (score 3):

These are all very generic questions that show you haven't invested any time in reading the Microsoft documentation; these things are very extensively documented.

Yes, you need AD to run exchange. No, you don't need two of each.
This all depends on your requirements, which you don't seem to have.

Comment: Correction: You **want** two of each. I'd just follow the MS documentation, which doesn't state that redundancy is *required*. A marginally more intelligent question from the OP would have helped, too.

Comment: In which case, I'd say MS are living in a fantasy world.. based on past experience, I'd also say that's not a surprise.

Comment: Well, since the products *technically* don't require redundancy, you can hardly expect them to say otherwise :) I don't doubt that they do advise it in any Best Practices documents on the subject.